# Set chezschme run as geiser-default-implementation

Tags: emacs, scheme, org-mode, chez-scheme

I installed chezscheme

```
$ chezscheme
Chez Scheme Version 9.5
Copyright 1984-2017 Cisco Systems, Inc.

> (define a (list 4 5 6 ))
> (set-car! a 9)
> a
(9 5 6)
```

and configure it as geiser-default-implementation

```
(require 'geiser)
(setq geiser-active-implementations '(chez guile racket chicken mit chibi gambit))
(add-hook 'scheme-mode-hook 'geiser-mode)
(setq geiser-default-implementation 'chez)
```

Nonetheless, When issue C-c C-c with org src

```
#+begin_src scheme :session sicp :lexical t
(define a (list 2 3 4))
(set-car! a 9)
a
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
```

It was buffering for a long while prompt that in the minibuffer 'chez go and up'

but run MIT-scheme instead.

The error:

```
MIT/GNU Scheme running under GNU/Linux
Type `^C' (control-C) followed by `H' to obtain information about interrupts.

Copyright (C) 2019 Massachusetts Institute of Technology
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions. There is NO warranty; not even for
MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Image saved on Thursday September 5, 2019 at 11:51:46 AM
  Release 10.1.10 || Microcode 15.3 || Runtime 15.7 || SF 4.41 || LIAR/x86-64 4.118
;Warning: Invalid keyword: "/home/me/.emacs.d/.local/straight/build/geiser/scheme/chez/geiser/geiser.ss"
;Warning: Unhandled command line options: ("/home/me/.emacs.d/.local/straight/build/geiser/scheme/chez/geiser/geiser.ss")
```

Additional:

Add `geiser-chez-binary`

```
(setq geiser-active-implementations '(chez guile))
(setq geiser-chez-binary "chez")
(add-hook 'scheme-mode-hook 'geiser-mode)
(setq geiser-default-implementation 'chez)
```

And run

```
#+begin_src scheme   :session sicp :lexical t :results output
(define b (list 3 4))

#+end_src
```

it report

```
    apply: Searching for program: No such file or directory, chez
```

Then I append `chez` to `org-babel-do-load-languages` and change keyword scheme to chez

```
#+begin_src chez   :session sicp :lexical t :results output
(define b (list 3 4))

#+end_src
```

It report:

```
  No org-babel-execute function for chez!
```

Removed mit-scheme package and it works

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, Geiser thinks Chez Scheme's executable is `scheme`, however, it's not, Chez Scheme uses `chez` and Mit Scheme uses `scheme` and `mit-scheme`. You need to put the following in your Emacs init file:

```
(setq geiser-chez-binary "chez")
```

Here is `geiser-chez-binary`'s docstring (I have already change it to chez):

> geiser-chez-binary is a variable defined in `geiser-chez.el'.
>   Its value is "chez"
>   Original value was "scheme"
>
> Documentation:
>   Name to use to call the Chez Scheme executable when starting a REPL.
>
> You can customize this variable.

Comment: ty, I revised the question, but it report `Searching for program: No such file or directory, chez`

Comment: Removed mit-scheme package and set geiser-chez binary back to `scheme', it works. I appended the screenshot to the question.